# is sharing a paid product that I got for free from someone and again sharing/leaking that same product with someone/everyone else haram?

Tags: halal-haram, money, business, fatwa

this is a **digital downloadable** product. Like a cracked file/product.

Comment: Try rephrasing questions like this in simpler English, such as "*Is it wrong to receive and pass on stolen property?*".  When euphemisms, such as "that I got for free" are eliminated, the answer will usually become much more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

We read in the Holy Quran (An-Nisa 29)

يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِيْنَ آمَنُوْا لَا تَأْكُلُوا أَمْوَالَكُمْ بَيْنَكُمْ بِالبَاطِلِ إِلَّا أَنْ تَكُوْنَ تِجَارَةً عَنْ تَرَاضٍ مِنْكُمْ
“O you who believe do not consume wealth between you through falsehood; except, that it is trade/commerce which you are mutually satisfied with.”

By this, we are bound to a commercial treaty that is fair and voluntary. In the case of a software, where the developer would grant a paid licence, using the software without that license is not a trade or commerce both are mutually satisfied with and it's thus haram.